# How to iterate an object and use if statement to check a property's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, return, javascript-objects

I'm trying to filter a property called 'miles' in an array of objects.
It should compare the value of the property 'miles' and return those only less than the user's miles.
Next, push the value of the property 'city' into an empty array and return it.

I can't get it to return the cities/countries as it's just returning an empty array.

Here's my code:

```
let flights = [{origin: 'AEP', destinations:[{city: 'PARIS', miles: 500}, {city: 'BOLZANO', miles: 200}, {city: 'DUBAI', miles: 400}]}, {origin: 'MXP', destinations: [{city: 'SAINT-TROPEZ', miles:  30}]},{origin: 'AEP', destinations: [{city: 'LISBON', miles: 30}, {city: 'MADRID', miles: 700}, {city: 'NICE', miles: 200}]}]

let user = {
   name: 'Elena',
   miles: 450,
   origin: 'AEP'
}
```

```
function closureTrip(flights){
    let list = [];
    let array = [];

        return function(user) {
            for (let i = 0; i < flights.length; i++) {
                if (flights[i].origin === user.origin) {
                    list.push(flights[i].destinations);

                    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++){
                        if(list[j].miles <= user.miles){
                            array.push(list[j].city);
                        }
                        return array
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

What I expected:
`closureTrip(flights)(user) => [ 'BOLZANO', 'DUBAI', 'LISBON', 'NICE' ]`

What I got:
`closureTrip(flights)(user) => []`

Comment: The `return` prevents the arrays from being properly iterated.

Answer (score 0):

First, use filter to keep the entries with the correct origin. Then use flatMap to get all destinations from all of those entries in one array. Then, filter the destinations that aren't too far. Finally, for each entry, return only the city property. The result will be an array.

```js
let flights = [{origin: 'AEP', destinations:[{city: 'PARIS', miles: 500}, {city: 'BOLZANO', miles: 200}, {city: 'DUBAI', miles: 400}]}, {origin: 'MXP', destinations: [{city: 'SAINT-TROPEZ', miles:  30}]},{origin: 'AEP', destinations: [{city: 'LISBON', miles: 30}, {city: 'MADRID', miles: 700}, {city: 'NICE', miles: 200}]}]

let user = {
   name: 'Elena',
   miles: 450,
   origin: 'AEP'
}

console.log(
  flights.filter(i => i.origin===user.origin)
    .flatMap(i => i.destinations)
    .filter(i => i.miles <= user.miles)
    .map(i => i.city)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get all elements in the array with the same origin as the user.
2. Use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to create a single one-dimensional array of all the cities from the previous step.
3. Use `Array#filter` again to get only the cities whose miles count does not exceed the user.
4. Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract only the names of those cities.

```js
let flights = [{origin: 'AEP', destinations:[{city: 'PARIS', miles: 500}, {city: 'BOLZANO', miles: 200}, {city: 'DUBAI', miles: 400}]}, {origin: 'MXP', destinations: [{city: 'SAINT-TROPEZ', miles:  30}]},{origin: 'AEP', destinations: [{city: 'LISBON', miles: 30}, {city: 'MADRID', miles: 700}, {city: 'NICE', miles: 200}]}];
let user = {
   name: 'Elena',
   miles: 450,
   origin: 'AEP'
};
function closureTrip(flights) {
    return user => 
      flights.filter(f => f.origin === user.origin).flatMap(f => f.destinations)
             .filter(o => o.miles <= user.miles).map(o => o.city);
}
console.log(closureTrip(flights)(user));
```

Comment: Hello! Can you help me out?

Comment: @AndresHernandez With what?

Comment: I have an to do an exercise but can't seem to figure it out. I'll send you a link

Answer (score 0):

1. `filter` the flights whose origin matches the user.
2. `loop` in filtered flights and `filter` those flights whose destination miles are less than the user's miles.
3. `map` the filtered destinations and keep only the city.
4. `merge` the result with the spread operator.

Working demo-

```js
let flights = [{origin: 'AEP', destinations:[{city: 'PARIS', miles: 500}, {city: 'BOLZANO', miles: 200}, {city: 'DUBAI', miles: 400}]}, {origin: 'MXP', destinations: [{city: 'SAINT-TROPEZ', miles:  30}]},{origin: 'AEP', destinations: [{city: 'LISBON', miles: 30}, {city: 'MADRID', miles: 700}, {city: 'NICE', miles: 200}]}];

let user = {
  name: 'Elena',
  miles: 450,
  origin: 'AEP'
}

let result = [];
flights.filter(f => f.origin == user.origin).forEach(f => {
  let r = f.destinations.filter(d => d.miles < user.miles).map(i => i.city)
  result = [...result, ...r]
})

console.log(result)
```